# Column Order with ui-grid-grouping

Tags: angular-ui-grid

i'm struggling with the [Ui-Grid](http://ui-grid.info/). I am using the grouping option to group my results. This works pretty fine, but in the documentation of this feature [Grouping](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/209_grouping) you can find the following statement:

> Optionally (and by default) grouped columns are moved to the front of the grid, which provides a more visually pleasing effect. In order to avoid creating a dependency on pinning, this is done by moving the columns themselves as part of the grouping feature, not through use of the pinning feature.

My understanding is, that it would be possible to disable this behavior. But i am not able to find how i can do so.
I want to have an action-column in the front of every entry.
Can anyone tell me how i disable the behavior that the "grouped" columns are always the first in the grid?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Found it out by myself:
You need to set the value "moveGroupColumns" to false
This value belongs to the gridOptions object